# Doubt: Cauchy Equation over real

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

[image]

I was going through [Evan Chen's Functional Equation handout handout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLLeU.png)

I couldn't under stant the second and the third  bulleted points , can someone explain me ?

Comment: What don't you understand about them? E.g. do you know what it means for a function to be bounded above in an interval, or when an interval is nontrivial?

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes, I couldn't understand by the term bounded

Comment: $f$ is bounded from above on $S$ (here $f$ is a function and $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$) iff there is some $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)<b$ for all $x\in S$. "Bounded from below" is similar, but with "$>$" instead of "$<$" - and note that we could replace $<$ (or $>$) with $\le$ (or $\ge$) without changing the meaning.

Comment: @NoahSchweber , I see , I think I got the meaning of boundness but what do we mean by a non- trivial interval ?

Comment: Check out [this](https://mathematicalolympiads.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/101-problems-in-algebra.pdf) ,only algebra problems from training of US  IMO team and congratulations, a quarter of $10$K rep

Comment: @BabaYaga thanks I will sure see through it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is bounded above if there exist $M$ such that $\forall x \in I ,(I \subseteq R)$ then, $$f(x) \le M $$
on the other hand if we have $ \ge $ in the equation then it's called bounded below

Comment: oh.. okay, so for function f (x)=x+1 then for all 0 \le x \le 10 , we get f(x) \le 11 , then we will call it it bounded , right ?

Comment: But here , what do we mean by a non-trivial bound ?

Comment: if$ I \in R   \text{ and }  I \neq 0 $ then it's called non-trivial interval

Comment: You've got the quantifiers in the wrong order. It's bounded if there exists an $M$ such that for all $x$... The value of $M$ shouldn't depend on $x$.

Answer (score 4):

A real valued function $f$ is bounded above on  a set $S$ is there exist $M$ such that $f(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in S$. It is bounded below on   $S$ is there exist $m$ such that $f(x) \geq m$ for all $x \in S$. It is bounded if it is bounded above and below.

A non trivial interval is an interval of one of the following types where $a<b$ and $c \in \mathbb R$:

$(a,b),[a,b),(a,b], [a,b], (-\infty, \infty), (c,\infty), [c,\infty)$, $(-\infty, c), (-\infty, c]$.

Comment: oh, I see,  thanks ! Can you also explain me the third point if possible ? Thanks!!

Comment: @Shubhangi In the plane consider the open disk with center $(a,b)$ and radius $\sqrt {\epsilon}$. The assumption in the last part  is that the point $(x,f(x))$ on tee graph of $f$ never lies in this disk for any value of $x$.

Comment: Oh yes! I got it thanks a lot :)